# Rails3 RegexpError (regular expression too big: /password|password_confirmation)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I'm using Rails 3.0.0 with Authlogic 2.1.6 and from time to time I'm getting this error message:

> RegexpError (regular expression too big:
>   /password|password_confirmation....

It results with internal server error  and I have to restart my server to get it work again. Anyone know how to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's sounding as though the :length of the password and/or password_confirmation fields is too long.  Do a validation first:  validates_length_of :password … to keep too large of passwords from being entered.